# How do I determine if an application is started using the OpenShift v2 REST API?

Tags: rest, openshift

I am using the OpenShift REST API to manage my applications, and while I can start and stop applications, I fail to see how I can determine if an application is started or stopped.

Essentially I am trying to determine the "Status" as seen here:
[image: WildFly cartridge with status]

Using `rhc`, I am able to determine the state using `rhc app show --state <app-name>`, however I do not see any way to do this through the REST API.

How do I determine the status of an application using the REST API?